# How do you get the characteristic polynomial of a recursion?

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, fibonacci-numbers, characteristic-polynomial

For example, the characteristic polynomial of the Fibonacci sequence is $x^2 -x -1$. What are the steps involved in this?

Comment: [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Characteristic_polynomial)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the computational answer, write the recurrence in the form $c_{n+k}f_{n+k}+c_{n+k-1}f_{n+k-1}+\cdots+c_nf_n=0$. Then, the characteristic polynomial will be $c_{n+k}x^k + c_{n+k-1}x^{k-1}+\cdots + c_n=0$. The notation looks kind of messy, but examples will help. If you want an explanation of why it's called "characteristic polynomial" and how it relates to linear algebra, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4521205/characteristic-polynomial-of-linear-recurrences?rq=1).

For fibonacci numbers, we have $F_{n+2} = F_{n+1}+F_n$, so $F_{n+2}-F_{n+1}-F_n=0$, giving us $c(x) = x^2-x-1$. If you want, you can think of it as simply replacing $F_n \to x^n$, $F_{n+1}\to x^{n+1}$, etc., and dividing by $x^n$. Notice another interesting property - the characteristic polynomial doesn't depending on the starting value $F_0$ and $F_1$. For example, if we instead define the Lucas sequence $2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, \cdots$ with the same recurrence, we will get the same polynomial $x^2 - x - 1$.

Another example would be the recurrence $F_{n+4}=2F_{n+3}-F_n$. Then, $F_{n+4}-2F_{n+3}+5F_n=0$, giving us $x^4-2x^3+5=0$. Be careful with the missing terms (that's why I suggest using the $F_n \to x^n$ method to visualise it better).

Hope this helps!